# "before increasing" or "before increased"

Tags: word-choice

which sentence is correct : (I'm writing about a graph)

• Flour consumption had a little drop  in mid 30s before increasing again in 1940

• Flour consumption had a little drop  in mid 30s before increased again in 1940

Also, what if I want to change "again" to "along with ..." ?

• Flour consumption had a little drop  in mid 30s before ________ (increased/increasing) along with cereal consumption in 1940

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct as you've written it.

However, you can make the second one correct with one extra word:

"Flour consumption had a little drop in mid 30s before **it** increased again in 1940."

(The pronoun "it" in this case stands in place of repeating the subject "flour consumption".)